# Small display of guest Ubuntu in VirtualBox

Tags: ubuntu, arch-linux, virtualbox

I'm running Ubuntu Bionic Beaver inside VirtualBox with Arch Linux 5.3.12 as the host operating system.

I've selected the default options while going through VirtualBox' "Create Virtual Machine" dialog.

I've installed guest additions using `pacman -Sy virtualbox-guest-utils`.

This is what I see:

[image: screenshot Ubuntu inside VirtualBox with lots of space unused]

Ubuntu doesn't fill the available space and it doesn't adapt its size when resizing the VirtualBox window.

How can I make Ubuntu inside VirtualBox use all that empty space?

Comment: You need to install **Guest Additions** on the guest, not the host.

Answer (score 0):

## Select VBoxSVGA as the graphics controller

You can fix this by selecting VBoxSVGA in the VM's settings. Go to "Display" → "Screen" → "Graphics Controller":

[image: VirtualBox graphics controller settings]

This way you get a guest operating system that fills the whole window:

[image: Ubuntu with VBoxSVGA]

The default graphics controller for Linux guests is VMSVGA. [Here's](https://superuser.com/questions/1403123/what-are-differences-between-vboxvga-vmsvga-and-vboxsvga-in-virtualbox) an explanation of the different graphics controllers.